# Django multiple SQL join when no backwards relation are created (related_name='+')?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, join

I need to execute this SQL statement (see below) using Django's ORM. I've to join 3 Django models.

This is my SQL requirement:

```
select a.attr_a, c.attr_c
from table_a as a 
left join table_b as b on a.a_id = b.a_id and b.d_id = 1
left join table_c as c on a.a_id = c.a_id and c.d_id = 2
where b.attr_b = 'foo' and c.attr_c = 'bar'
```

Then here are my Django models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    a_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    attr_a = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'table_a'


class B(models.Model):
    b_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    attr_b = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    fk_to_a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='+')
    fk_to_d = models.ForeignKey(D, related_name='+')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_b'


class C(models.Model):
    c_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    attr_c = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    fk_to_a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='+')
    fk_to_d = models.ForeignKey(D, related_name='+')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_c'


class D(models.Model):
    d_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    attr_d = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table_d'
```

Is there a way to resolve this with a single Django ORM query? Otherwise, could you show me how?

Comment: I think the joins require the `related_name`, but you can probably get the same results using a subquery.  ex `D.objects.filter(d_id__in=C.objects.all().values('fk_to_d'))` gives you all `D` objects that are referenced by `C` objects.